# unattended-upgrades: everything except new major versions

Tags: debian, unattended-upgrades

I want unattended-upgrades to upgrade everything automatically on my Debian bullyseye system, except for new major version (i.e. not bookworm, when it's released).

I couldn't find anything describing this scenario, and I had a couple of ideas of how to do this:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
      "origin=*";
}

Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
      "origin=Debian,codename=^((?!bullseye).)*";
};
```

Or this:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
      "origin=*";
}

Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
      "origin=Debian,codename=bookworm";
};
```

Can anyone give me some guidance on whether either of these would work, or whether there's a better strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t determined by `unattended-upgrades`, it’s determined by the repositories you have configured. If your Debian repositories are selected by codename (`bullseye`), and you only have those configured, `unattended-upgrades` won’t upgrade you automatically to the next release of Debian.

(In other words, don’t specify `stable` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` etc.)